# QScrollArea::ensureVisible() and QScrollArea::setWidget()

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I encountered another problem with `QScrollArea`, after I got help for [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653233/qlabelsetpixmap-and-qscrollareasetwidget), which was somewhat similar.

The problem now is that `ensureVisible()` does nothing if you create a scroll area and a label, set the label to be the scroll area's widget, and then load an image into the label - **after** `setWidget()`:

This example illustrates the problem, just replace `/path/to/some/image.png` with some real image on your computer:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
QLabel *label = new QLabel(scrollArea);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
scrollArea->setWidget(label);
label->setPixmap(QPixmap("/path/to/some/image.png"));
label->setFixedSize(label->pixmap()->size());
scrollArea->ensureVisible(10000, 10000);
scrollArea->show();
```

If the `setPixmap()` is called **before** `setWidget()`, `ensureVisible()` will work.

Also, the problem is reproducible even though I call `setWidgetResizable()` and even `setFixedSize()`.

Why does this happen, and is it possible to make `ensureVisible()` work without changing the order of `setWidget()` and `setPixmap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ensureVisible(10000, 10000);` the scrollArea hasn't adjusted the widget's size yet. That is why it won't work.

If you create a slot that calls `ensureVisible` and use `QTimer::singleShot` to call that slot with the timeout set to 0 (you can also use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with queued connection), it will work, even if you set the scroll area's widget before you set the pixmap on the label.

What also works is, if you call `ensureVisible` after you call `show`. But this only works if your `scrollArea` is a top level window. If you embed it to a widget, it will not work.

Comment: Then why does it work if `setPixmap()` is before `setWidget()`? Besides, the widget is resized properly (thanks to your previous answer), only `ensureVisible()` doesn't work.

Comment: @sashoalm It doesn't seem to work properly even if you set the pixmap before calling `setWidget`.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but I had other things and had forgotten about the question. When I swap the `label->setPixmap` and `scrollArea->setWidget` lines, the image is shown initially scrolled on my computer. Is your image big enough? It might be that there's no need to scroll, and that's why it doesn't.

Comment: @sashoalm My image was 600x600. The window size was well below that. The scroll bars were visible. I tried to make it scroll to the bottom right corner, but it only scrolled maybe 50 pixels to the right and down. But when I used `QTimer::singleShot` it scrolled to the bottom right corner properly. The order of `label->setPixmap` and `scrollArea->setWidget` seemed to make no difference.

Comment: Can you try with a bigger image, like 1000x1000? It still might be because of that, because in my case, [the scroll bars moved, but not all the way](http://imgur.com/1OXI25A) (don't know why). The image was about 1500x780.

Comment: @sashoalm It seems to scroll close to the bottom right corner but not quite. I'm not sure what's with that.